# Combine two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
   table name: tags
          id (int)
          tag_name (vharchar)    

   table name: messages
          id (int)
          message_title (vharchar)
          message_content(vharchar)

    table name: message_tag
          message_id (int)
          tag_id (int)
```

I have tried this code but it didn't work(returns empty)

```
SELECT messages.message_title, messages.message_content, tags.tag_name
            FROM messages
            INNER JOIN message_tag ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
            INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = message_tag.tag_id
            WHERE message_tag.tag_id =191
            AND message_tag.tag_id =19
            AND message_tag.tag_id =31
            ORDER BY RAND( )
            LIMIT 20
```

I want to select random 20 rows which are connected to tag 191, 19 and 31

Comment: how can it fetch you any record with all the `3 tags` in just one `int` field?

Comment: message_tag.tag_id =191 AND message_tag.tag_id =19 AND message_tag.tag_id =31? I guess you mean to use 'or' not and? 'And' probably will end up with nothing.

Comment: you need to elaborate more by posting some data

Comment: One tag can have more than one message and one message can have more than one tag. So i want messages which connected to all those three tags. Not one or two. All of those three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT messages.message_title, messages.message_content, tags.tag_name
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN message_tag ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
        INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = message_tag.tag_id
        WHERE message_tag.tag_id IN (191, 19, 31)
        ORDER BY RAND( )
        LIMIT 20
```

Use `IN` instead of `AND`. This will bring you messages which are linked to one at least of those particular tags.

**Update:** *IF* you wanted to get messages where all 3 tags are present, you would do this instead (assuming your rows in message_tag are unique):

```
    SELECT messages.message_title, messages.message_content, tags.tag_name
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN message_tag ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
        INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = message_tag.tag_id
        WHERE message_tag.tag_id IN (191, 19, 31)
        GROUP BY messages.id
        HAVING COUNT(messages.id) > 2
        ORDER BY RAND( )
        LIMIT 20
```

Comment: This returns message that have one or more of those three tags.  I *think* that the OP wants messages that have *all three* of those tags.

Comment: Yes Dems. You are right. I want messages connected all three of those tags

Answer (score 3):

It will **not** retrieve rows because your condition is invalid. It will always result to `false`. `tag_id` can only have **1 possible value**, not many. Try this:

```
SELECT messages.message_title, messages.message_content, tags.tag_name
FROM messages
         INNER JOIN message_tag 
              ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
         INNER JOIN tags 
              ON tags.id = message_tag.tag_id
WHERE message_tag.tag_id IN (191, 19, 31)
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 20
```

use `IN` clause instead of `AND`

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT messages.message_title, messages.message_content, tags.tag_name
FROM messages
         INNER JOIN message_tag 
              ON messages.id = message_tag.message_id
         INNER JOIN tags 
              ON tags.id = message_tag.tag_id
WHERE message_tag.tag_id IN (191, 19, 31)
GROUP BY messages.message_title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: This returns message that have one or more of those three tags. I *think* that the OP wants messages that have *all three* of those tags.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `message_tag.tag_id =191 AND message_tag.tag_id =19 AND message_tag.tag_id =31` represent the intersection of disjoned sets, so it represents an empty set.

You need rather the union of this sets. Simply replace the `AND` with `OR`.